# CSS Transition Timing Issue

Tags: css

I am trying to recreate the transition seen here - http://piccsy.com/investors - It's the banner on the right hand side of the page that moves on mouseover. It says "Executive Summary".

Here is what I have so far. I am close but just can;t seem to get it to be EXACTLY the same. For some reason, the text inside the container moves choppy unlike the container which is smooth.

http://jsfiddle.net/fuwLeye0/

```
<div id="executive-summary-bar" style="text-align: center;">
<a href="#executive-summary">Executive Summary </a></div>

#executive-summary-bar a{color:#ffffff; height:20px; margin-top:-5px;}    
#executive-summary-bar a:hover{color:#ffffff;}

#executive-summary-bar {
    height:20px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #373435;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin-top: -10px;
    padding: 32px 3px 7px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    width: 68px;
    transition: height 1s;
    -moz-transition: height 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: height 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: height 1s; /* Opera */
    -ms-transition: height 1s; /* IE9 (maybe) */
}    
#executive-summary-bar:hover{
    height:35px;
    padding: 46px 3px 7px;
}    
#executive-summary-bar:after{
    border-left: 37px solid transparent;
    border-right: 37px solid transparent;
    border-top: 36px solid #373435;
    content: "";
    left:0;
    position: absolute;
    top:100%;
    width: 0;
}

div#executive-summary-bar {
    //right: 50px;
    //top: -40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text position within your `<div/>` is controlled by `padding-top` but you're only animating `height`. If you add `padding-top` to your transition declarations, [you get the desired effect](http://jsfiddle.net/7318zto1/).

```
transition: height 1s, padding-top 1s;
```

Comment: That works great in the jsfiddle, and I implemented it on my page - http://funmedusa.com , but it doesn't look good at all on my site. It's still really choppy. Any ideas?

Comment: @Carl on your site, `#executive-summary-bar:hover a` has `position: relative; bottom: -10px;`, possibly from an earlier attempt to fix it. Removing those declarations should get it working.